# Compare two lists of variables in python

Tags: python, variables

I have got two lists in python with elements. I want to perform some checks in those two lists. My lists are the following:

```
list_A = [["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_C'", "'4'", '0.714', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_D'", "'5'", '0.778', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_D'", "'5'", '0.226', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_D'", "'5'", '0.222', '\n'], ...]
list_B = [["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_B'", "'2'", '1.000', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_C'", "'3'", '1.000', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_D'", "'4'", '1.000', '\n'], ["'EASY'", "'LEVEL_D'", "'4'", '0.290', '\n'], ...]
```

For the variable "EASY" and for the variable level which takes the values (LEVEL_A - LEVEL_F) there is a third variable correspond to score (1-6) and the confidence variable (0-1). What I want to do is to compare the two lists for the variable easy and level and to find in all cases which of the two lists (list_A and list_B) has greater score and with which confidence. How can I do so?

The way that I am constructing my rules, in the beginning I ve got the rows derived from an executable and filter them into lists. A vector example for my lists is the following:

```
Rule: ('EASY', 'LEVEL_E') ==> ('4') , 0.182 
'EASY' 'LEVEL_E' '4'  0.182 
["'EASY'",  "'LEVEL_E'", , "'4'", '0.182', '\n']
```

and the code that I am using for creating the vector:

```
 for row in my_lines:
   print row
   row = re.sub('[()]', "", row)
   row = row.replace("Rule: ", "")
   row = row.replace(",", "")
   row = row.replace("==>", "")
   print row
   split = re.split(r' +', row)
   print split
```

Then as soon as I have created my lists i sort them with the second element which corresponds to the variable Level:

```
list_A.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
list_B.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

**EDIT:** I have sorted the lists with the variable level. Now I want to compare the two lists regarding the score for all the variable levels. When a level does not exist then the score is zero and when the same score exist twice the system should prefer the one with highest confidence. How can I compare all the possibles values for the variable level?

Comment: Why are the sublists not ordered? Sometimes 'LEVEL' is the first item and other times 'EASY'.

Comment: The list are not ordered. I need to do some kind of sorting but i am not realyl familiar with how can I do it in python and strings.

Comment: Also, how are these lists generated? Is using objects/dictionaries an option?

Comment: Clearly, the data structured is not adapted. You should use dictionnaries with keys such as 'Level' and 'score'. Then just build a list of dictionnaries which can be easily sorted and handled in the same way.

Comment: how did you produced these list? looks they are the result of an existing python code. If it's the case, can you show us the said python code ?

Comment: It is the result of an executable file. The lists were created using association rules and the order is the posted one. Can I create dictionaries using the above lists?

Comment: Show us the code that generates these lists. It looks like you should do it in a different way. It would also be good to know *why* you have these two lists. Please describe your goals and requirements in detail.

Comment: I put the variable easy in the first index of the list. Then how can I sort the list using the string variable level?

Comment: So the input consists of lines like this `"Rule: ('4', 'EASY') ==> ('LEVEL_E',) , 0.182"`, the executable produces them in an arbitrary order and you don't have control over how it produces the data? What is the executable?

Comment: The order that the executable produces is weird and the desired one. The executable creates association rules from a database of data. In my list I have put variable easy in the first index, then i have the variable level and then the score for my both lists list_A and list_B. Now I need to sort the lists with the second index and then compare them list_A[1], list_B[1], but how can i sort strings?

Comment: Please revert the question to the original version with the unsorted lists and add the solution with the sorted lists to the 'EDIT' paragraph. And add the list generation code again.

Comment: Oke just did it.

Comment: Why are the sublists in the same order now ('EASY' first then 'LEVEL')? Since you now have the same levels several times in the list, you've invalidated my answer, but I think it could still work with a defaultdict. It's also not really clear to me what you want to do with the sublists. Do you want to get the average score or confidence for the levels with the same name? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to compare two lists regarding the level variable. Therefore for level = 'LEVEL_A', ..., 'LEVEL_F' to find which list has a greater score value. In the case I have duplicate sublists I want to remove the ones with the smaller confidence.

Comment: So you want to see if list_a or b has the greater score for 'LEVEL_A', then which one has the greater score for 'LEVEL_B' and so on for all levels from 'A' to 'F'?

Comment: Exactly, and in the case that one of the two lists do not have any item for a specific level to direct choose the other one, or in the case the level item is missing in both cases to choose directly list_B.

Comment: Finally, I manage to remove the duplicates, now I am trying to pefrom the comparison.

Comment: Since you're discarding the duplicates, the dictionary approach would work again.

Comment: [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)s would be good here.

Comment: I went for the zip solution, was really easy to implement.

Comment: Post your solution to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to my question was to order the lists just using a simple sort for the strings and then zip the two lists in order to be able to perform the comparison. The code used is the following:

```
list_A.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
list_B.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
res = zip(list_A, list_B)
```

However it seems that the dictionary solution proposed in the previous answer is more efficient than using the lists.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but it would be a lot more pleasant to have the data in a dict of dicts:

```
dict_a = {
    'LEVEL_D': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 1, 'confidence': 0.778},
    'LEVEL_F': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 6, 'confidence': 0.750},
    'LEVEL_C': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 7, 'confidence': 0.714},
    }

dict_b = {
    'LEVEL_F': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 8, 'confidence': 0.800},
    'LEVEL_B': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 2, 'confidence': 0.900},
    'LEVEL_D': {'difficulty': 'EASY', 'score': 3, 'confidence': 1.000},
    }
```

Then you could write a simple for loop to get the desired values of the inner dicts:

```
for level in dict_a:
    if level in dict_b:
        stats_a = dict_a[level]
        stats_b = dict_b[level]
        score_a = stats_a['score']
        score_b = stats_b['score']
        conf_a = stats_a['confidence']
        conf_b = stats_b['confidence']
        print(level, score_a, score_b, conf_a, conf_b)
```

We need to figure out how to rearrange the data in this way. The list of lists approach could actually work, too, but less efficient. The main problem is that the data is not ordered correctly.

**Edit:** To get the name of the list with the higher score for the specific level you can do this:

```
for level in dict_a:
    if level in dict_b:
        stats_a = dict_a[level]
        stats_b = dict_b[level]
        container = 'A' if stats_a['score'] > stats_b['score'] else 'B'
        print('Container {} has the higher score for level {}.'.format(container, level))
```

Comment: The thing is easier to find a solution with list of lists than re-arrange it into dictionary as it is. I have manage to sort the lists through the level and now i just need to perform the comparisons for all possible values of variable level= {LEVEL_A - LEVEL_F}

Comment: There are also cases that I have the same variable twice with different confidence or score.